# Java: Detecting generic type by Enum

Tags: java, generics

I have a `class` with a generic parameter `T` say `Action`. Every `Action` has an `ActionType`, given in the constructor. For example, it could be `GET_STRING`. Depending on the `ActionType`, I would like Java to detect the `Action`'s generic type `T`. 
Example:

```
public enum ActionType {
    GET_STRING(String.class), GET_BOOLEAN(Boolean.class);

    private ActionType(Class clazz) { this.clazz = clazz}
    private Class clazz;
    Class getType() { return clazz; }
}
```

Now I want `Action` to automatically have the type its `ActionType#getType()` returns.

```
public class Action<T> {
    public Action(ActionType type) {
        // magic
    }

    public T doAction() { ... }
}

String s = new Action(ActionType.GET_STRING).doAction();
```

Is that possible? Maybe in a way that the `enum` implements an `interface` or something similar?

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: No, not really.  That's not a thing you can do with enums.

Comment: maybe with a switch in class action. what is T?

Comment: This is not possible as generic types are resolved at compile-time. This means that when after you compile, T will be erased and (explained simply) you must assume that in runtime all instances of T will behave as if they were of type Object (or String if you declared as <T extends String>), so there is no actual way to tell at runtime which is the class assigned to T, unless you have an actual object of type T to determine its class using the instanceof operator or reflection utilities. Maybe if you elaborate on what are you trying to accomplish there could be some different approach.

Comment: @Alberto My goal it to automatically get an Action<String>, for example, when I construct it like new Action(ActionType.GET_STRING). I don‘t want to cast it, since I just want it to be type-safe.